# How to create dicts and add to them at the same time in a loop in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create dictionaries in a loop. But the names of these new dicts originate in a list containing hundreds of items, so I don't know these names in advance. After creating them I also need to constantly add to these dicts in the same loop.
I believe the `if "vars()[i]" not in locals():` line is failing in this code cause it keeps overwriting the dicts, instead of adding to them. The `(vars()[i])[now] = numbers` is also fishy, I believe this will also throw an error, if I ever get past the if statement.

```
import datetime, time

longlist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
numbers = 1

while True:
    for i in longlist:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now = now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
        if "vars()[i]" not in locals():
            vars()[i] = {now: numbers}
        else:
            (vars()[i])[now] = numbers
        numbers = numbers + 1
    
    time.sleep(1)

        
    print(apple)
    print(banana)
    print(cherry)
```

Comment: you are using i as a key but instead you have to use 'i' as a key. Also you have to use fstring to format. otherwise it will take vars()['i] as a whole string not the value of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime, time

longlist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
numbers = 1

while True:
    for i in longlist:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now = now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")

        if f"{vars()['i']}" not in locals():
            vars()[i] = {now: numbers}
        else:
            (vars()[i])[now] = numbers
        numbers = numbers + 1
    
    time.sleep(1)

        
    print(apple)
    print(banana)
    print(cherry)
```

Answer (score 0):

because you have not defined what is 'locals' and 'vars' here, I can't get the full context. but I will recommend you to use two lists, one for already added items and one for new items to be added. Once you add list item to dictionary, use pop() method. dictionary does not accept duplicates, so if you try to add item that already exists, it will be updated in the dictionary. I recommend you o use any one of below methods for adding itms to the dictionary:

```
dictName["key"] = "value"
```

OR

```
dictName.update({"key": "value"})
```

Comment: what do you mean by defining vars and locals? They both are predefined in python

Comment: sorry. I completely forgot about the locals() dictionary and vars() function. I think I was wrong...btw, how are apple, banana,cherry getting printed? and what's the point here. i am u cause I am also pretty new to the concept here.

Comment: Every variable you create will be stored in predefined vars dictionary as 'varname':'value'. As you can see after iterating through list. the list elements are also stored as a key in vars and the value of those key is also a dict of {'time':'number'}.